# Creating another thread to get the current window (System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow)

Tags: c#, wpf

I need the current window to show a custom MessageBox.  I do this:

```
Window owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

sometimes it works.  Where it doesn't work, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: {"The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."}
InnerException: null
Message: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
```

Would a solution to be to kick this call off to a separate thread than the main thread?  If so, how do I do that?  Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to use the Dispatcher and Invoke/BeginInvoke to marshal the call back to the UI thread:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)() =>
{
       Window owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;

       // Use owner here - it must be used on the UI thread as well..
       ShowMyWindow(owner);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Working alternative of Reed Copsey's answer:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
       Window owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;

       // Use owner here - it must be used on the UI thread as well..
       ShowMyWindow(owner);
});
```