# How to access the DataContext of MainWindow from external classes?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my `MainWindow` I've created a `DataContext` that has a `ViewModel` and the methods of all controls are added to this. This is the code:

```
private void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModelClass viewModel = new ViewModelClass();
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

Now I've different classes (not window only classes) that need access to the control of MainWindow. How can I access MainWindow's `DataContext` from other classes? Note that I'm using different threads that need to update the UI.

Comment: Are you using MVVM pattern?

Why do you want to access the control from other classes? Instead try to change the properties from other classes with data binding :)

That's the best thing to do in WPF/MVVM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
var datacontext =  App.Current.MainWindow.DataContext
```

Comment: This return me InvalidOperationException

Comment: It throws this exception when you try to use it in different thread. If you have to get access to this in different thread try to use Dispatcher property of MainWindow as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249013/creating-another-thread-to-get-the-current-window-system-windows-application-cu.

Answer (score 0):

As adminSoftDK has mentioned, the below code should give you the viewmodel reference, provided the viewmodel is already initialized:

`var context = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext;`

One observation in your code - you are instantiating the viewmodel in the Loaded event. Ideally the viewmodel should be created:

1. in the constructor of the view class (MetroWindow constructor, in your case), or
2. in the XAML as

`<Window.DataContext>
     <namespace:ViewModelClass />
 </Window.DataContext>`

This ensures that the view loads up with an initial state data from the viewmodel.